# Variable Class count

Tags: r

I think the answer will be very simple, but I cannot figure it out. I am trying to count the number of certain class variables in my data frame. For example, the number of character variables.

```
lapply(jungle,is.character)
```

This returns each variable and whether or not (TRUE,FALSE) it is class character. Is there a way to simply obtain the number of character variables in the frame?

```
dim(lapply(jungle,is.character))
```

This returns NULL, but I feel that this answer does lie within dim() somewhere. I want my output to just be one single number, the amount of character variables.

Comment: I think you want `sum(sapply(jungle, is.character))`

Comment: In case you do want to know counts of all classes, `table(sapply(mtcars, class))` will do the trick, too.

Comment: Damn, I was so close. Thanks!